# Focus on specific input type text after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to focus on a specific text input after submit.

As I googled, lot of answer told me to use `$('#id').focus();`

But as `submit` function refreshes the page, focus() does not react as I expected.

Also setting `focus()` on ready function does not help, because it should not focus before submit.

Anyone could help?

Comment: Please post your sample code so we can see the details. Thanks!

Comment: Are you performing the `.focus()` inside `$(document).ready` or in a script at the bottom of the page? You can check by writing `console.log('Found element', $('#id'));` to see if the element is available in the dom.

Answer (score -1):

You have to focus on the input inside the submit event.

```
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault;
        $('#id').focus(); 
        etc...
    })
```